# VB6 DataGrid View need upload Query Output Data

Tags: vb6

I'm Just a beginner developing an application for my Work. Anyone please help I want to load the few selected column and selected row Output from Query result in to DataGrid View Control, I'm not getting any error in this code, but same time I'm not achieved the desired result. Please help me here.  Attached is the runtime screen where result is not achieved for you review:

[image]

**My code**

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorMsg    
Set ObjConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")    
Set ObjRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")  

FromCutoff = CDate(Text1.Text)    
ToCutoff = CDate(Text2.Text)

DataGrid1.ClearFields    
DataGrid1.Refresh    
Colcount = DataGrid1.Columns.Count    
ObjConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\04. Files & Documents\GL TMT\TMT_Database.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"

ObjRecordset.Open "Select [Assign_No], [ERP_No], [MEP_Code], [Standard_Activities], [Site_Specific_Activity_Name], [KPI_Type], [Activity_Nature], [Checklist_Activity], [Due_Date], [Due_Time], [Process_Status], [Process_Completion_Date], [Process_Completion_Time], [Review_Status], [Reviewer_Name] FROM [TMT_ACTIVITY_DATABASE] where [Process_Completed_By_ID] ='" & Environ("username") & "' and [MEP_Code] = '" & Combo1.Text & "' and [Process_Status] IN ('Completed','Not Applicable') and [Process_Completion_Date] between #" & FromCutoff & "# and #" & ToCutoff & "#", ObjConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

DataGrid1.ColumnHeaders = True    
DataGrid1.RecordSelectors = True    
rcount = ObjRecordset.RecordCount

If rcount > 0 And Colcount < 14 Then    
    For i = 2 To 14    
        DataGrid1.Columns.Add (i)    
    Next i    
End If

Me.DataGrid1.Columns(0).Caption = "Assign No."    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(1).Caption = "ERP No."    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(2).Caption = "MEP Code"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(3).Caption = "Standard Activities"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(4).Caption = "Site Specific Activity"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(5).Caption = "KPI Type"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(6).Caption = "Activity Nature"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(7).Caption = "Checklist Activity"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(8).Caption = "Due Date"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(9).Caption = "Due Time"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(10).Caption = "Process Status"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(11).Caption = "Completion Date"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(12).Caption = "Completion Time"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(13).Caption = "Review Status"    
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(14).Caption = "Reviewer Name"    
Set Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = ObjRecordset

ObjConnection.Close    
Recordset.Close    
Set ObjConnection = Nothing    
Set Recordset = Nothing    
Exit Sub

ErrorMsg:    
MsgBox "Input Error", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you coding in VB.NET? I don't recall any `DataGrid View` control for VBA

Comment: You have this question tagged with 3 different languages.  Is this VB.NET, VBA, or VB6?

Comment: i'm coding in VB 6.0

Comment: Did you check if your recordset is not empty?

Comment: I checked Recordset Recordcount it is not empty.... i have tried with few more coding line. provided below.... after my column name definition. Below are coding. Data field is showing different values based on query when i run with F8.

Comment: For j = 1 To rcount
Set Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = ObjRecordset
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(0).DataField = ObjRecordset.Fields("Assign_No")
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(1).DataField = ObjRecordset.Fields("ERP_No")
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(2).DataField = ObjRecordset.Fields("MEP_Code")
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(3).DataField = ObjRecordset.Fields("Standard_Activities")
Me.DataGrid1.Columns(4).DataField = ObjRecordset.Fields("Site_Specific_Activity_Name")
etc.... till column 14 ObjRecordset.MoveNext
Next j